# how to change a parentClass variable from ChildClass, and make that variable globally for all childs, so I can access the same data from all classes?

Tags: javascript, class

I have this code:

```js
class ParentClass {
  constructor() {
    /* at the start is 0 because we didn't call it */
    this.previusX = 0;
    this.previusY = 0;
    this.previusZ = 0;
  }

  // if we call a newChildClass() the previus values will not be 0 anymore, but the current x, y, z values.
  setLastPosition() {
    this.previusX = this.x;
    this.previusY = this.y;
    this.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(_obj) {
    super();
    // if there is no obj, then use the previus position (that is the last position)
    // this techically works because we use "??"
    this.x = _obj.x ? ? this.previusX;
    this.y = _obj.y ? ? this.previusY;
    this.z = _obj.z ? ? this.previusZ;

    // if result is not set, then it will be a error, but we will change it (here is work fine, no problem in that)
    this.result = "ERROR";
  }

  print() {
    this.result = `X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;
    // ❌ this is not working properly, technically
    // if I console.log previusX, previusY, previusZ, it will print the current x, y, z values,
    // but in the next ChildClass it doesn't remember the previus values that are save in parentClass

    // I thinked that if I have for example 10 childrens, the parent be only one
    // and all that children can get the previus values from the parentClass.
    this.setLastPosition();

    return this.result;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- see the next code snippet for the example of the problems -->
```

and when I want to change a `parentClass` variable from a `ChildClass`

the `parentClass` doesn't save the changed variable but gets reset every time.

*How can I make the ParentClass share the same variable on all other child?*

---

- the idea was the ParentClass will be only few (better only 1), but children can be more than 2 (can be also 10 similars).
- every child has a different object of data
- but every child have the same data inside the parentClass, 
  so if I redefine for example `this.previusX` all children now have the new value because we changed the parentClass.
- if a `childClass` get a null or undefined value in the `constructor()` then it will try to get the global variable `this.previus` from `parentClass`.
- how to not make reset the value in this.var in ParentClass after creating a new ChildClass? or making that be redefine globally so `0` won't be anymore the returned value but `this.x` for example.

> the only idea I have that can cause the problem is `super();` but not sure.
>
>  before asking here on StackOverflow I searched a lot but not finding anything (at least with javascript language, maybe in java but I am not familiar with it...)

---

**now here the code with example of errors and what I want, with also comments:**

> please run the code snippet for understanding the problem, and read also the comments in the html script tag

```js
class ParentClass {
  constructor() {
    /* at the start is 0 because we didn't call it */
    this.previusX = 0;
    this.previusY = 0;
    this.previusZ = 0;
  }

  // if we call a newChildClass() the previus values will not be 0 anymore, but the current x, y, z values.
  setLastPosition() {
    this.previusX = this.x;
    this.previusY = this.y;
    this.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(_obj) {
    super();
    // if there is no obj, then use the previus position (that is the last position)
    // this techically works because we use "??"
    this.x = _obj.x ?? this.previusX;
    this.y = _obj.y ?? this.previusY;
    this.z = _obj.z ?? this.previusZ;

    // if result is not set, then it will be a error, but we will change it (here is work fine, no problem in that)
    this.result = "ERROR";
  }

  print() {
    this.result = `X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;

    /* ❌ this is not working properly, technically
    if I console.log previusX, previusY, previusZ, it will print the current x, y, z values,
    but in the next ChildClass it doesn't remember the previus values that are save in parentClass

    I thinked that if I have for example 10 childrens, the parent be only one
     and all that children can get the previus values from the parentClass. */

    this.setLastPosition();

    return this.result;
  }
}

test();

function test() {
  // this is correct but in the next examples is not working because I wanted to that if _obj isn't defined it get the previus one.
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  }).print());

  // here since z is not defined
  // ❌ it need to be 3, but I don't know why is 0.
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 4,
    y: 5
  }).print());

  // ❌ this need to be "x: 4, y: 5, z: 3" by getting the previus values with "??"
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 3
  }).print());

  // ❌ this need to be "x:3, y:5, z:18"
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    z: 18
  }).print());

  // ✅ if there is all the values then is correct
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 8,
    y: 20,
    z: 30
  }).print());
}
```

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

---

---

---

---

---

**bonus:** *(don't see this, the problem is in the first code, this is only a bonus if you can, but I will accept your answer also if there is the before answer)*

> also is there a way to write something like this pseudocode?

```js
let one = new ParentClass();
let two = new ParentClass();

// now the child's class know their parentClass
one.childClass({x:10}).print();
one.childClass({y:30, z:10}).print();
one.childClass({ x: 15, z: 30 }).print();

// the previus values need to be different from the "one".
two.childClass({x:15}).print();
two.childClass({y:25}).print();
two.childClass({ z: 5, x: 30 }).print();

// the values are random, only to test and debugging purposes
```

> this code on top is not the correct syntax code, but maybe I tried to make you understand my wanted logic. 
> `parentClass` can share the same variables on all `ChildClass`, but every `ChildClass` have it own variables that can't be change... but `ParentClass` variables can be change by `ChildClass` and affect all other children.

**what I tried to archive this idea?** *(but is not work)*

[image]

I tried to console.log the `childClass`, and I saw that there is `Prototype` thing there, that has the `ParentClass`

so I tried to maybe access the ParentClass in the old way with `new ChildClass({}).Prototype.ParentClass` but not output anything

I am confused, I don't know why is not working, thanks if you help me.
[image]

---

so

1. child class can change a Parent class constructor
2. if a new child Class is created, the parent class doesn't need to be reset but needs to remember the last changed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR:

```js
ParentClass.myVariable = "something";
```

---

#### LONG ANSWER:

I think your problem is in `super()`

by this I mean that technically when you write `this.`

you are referring to the `ChildClass()` not the parent.

remember that when you call `super();`

javascript literally copies the `parentClass` and put everything inside the `childClass`

 so when you write `this.previusX` that value remains always inside the `ChildClass`

> which is great if you think about it, because don't make you have some side effects.

---

**so what it the solution?**

you always need to put that `super();` OR `this.` will not work.

but instead of referring to `this`,

try to refer to the class Name of the parent.

I know you tried to use `prototype` thing but is not working for you,

 but now days with the `CLASS` keyword, this became a lot easier with this `syntax sugar`

so just write something like this:

```js
ParentClass.myVariable = "something";
```

like this photo:

[image]
[image]

here the result of console:

[image]

> you see works great, there is no 0 there.

```js
class ParentClass {
  constructor() {
    this.previusX = 0;
    this.previusY = 0;
    this.previusZ = 0;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(_obj) {
    super();
    this.x = _obj.x ?? ParentClass.previusX;
    this.y = _obj.y ?? ParentClass.previusY;
    this.z = _obj.z ?? ParentClass.previusZ;

    this.result = "ERROR";
  }

  print() {
    this.result = `X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;
    this.setLastPosition();

    return this.result;
  }

  setLastPosition() {
    ParentClass.previusX = this.x;
    ParentClass.previusY = this.y;
    ParentClass.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

test();

function test() {
  // this is correct but in the next examples is not working because I wanted to that if _obj isn't defined it get the previus one.
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  }).print());

  // here since z is not defined
  // ❌ it need to be 3, but I don't know why is 0.
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 4,
    y: 5
  }).print());

  // ❌ this need to be "x: 4, y: 5, z: 3" by getting the previus values with "??"
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 3
  }).print());

  // ❌ this need to be "x:3, y:5, z:18"
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    z: 18
  }).print());

  // ✅ if there is all the values then is correct
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 8,
    y: 20,
    z: 30
  }).print());
}
```

---

⚠️ **but there is a extra bug!**

if `setLastPosition()` method don't get run at the start,

then `ParentClass` previous var it will be `undefined`,

and it won't get the 0 value.

**so why before was working, and for me seems to work?**

yes, in most of the cases it will work,

but if in the first `ChildClass` you didn't define the `x, y, z` then this will happen

example: `new ChildClass({ x: 1, y: 2 }` now all the other next `ChildClass`es without defined `z` will be `undefined`

```js
class ParentClass {
  constructor() {
    this.previusX = 0;
    this.previusY = 0;
    this.previusZ = 0;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(_obj) {
    super();
    this.x = _obj.x ?? ParentClass.previusX;
    this.y = _obj.y ?? ParentClass.previusY;
    this.z = _obj.z ?? ParentClass.previusZ;

    this.result = "ERROR";
  }

  print() {
    this.result = `X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;
    this.setLastPosition();

    return this.result;
  }

  setLastPosition() {
    ParentClass.previusX = this.x;
    ParentClass.previusY = this.y;
    ParentClass.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

test();

function test() {
  // this is correct but in the next examples is not working because I wanted to that if _obj isn't defined it get the previus one.
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  }).print());

  // here since z is not defined
  // ❌ it need to be 3, but I don't know why is 0.
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 4,
    y: 5
  }).print());

  // ❌ this need to be "x: 4, y: 5, z: 3" by getting the previus values with "??"
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 3
  }).print());

  // ❌ this need to be "x:3, y:5, z:18"
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    z: 18
  }).print());

  // ✅ if there is all the values then is correct
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 8,
    y: 20,
    z: 30
  }).print());
}
```

[image]

**quick solution** can be:

using another `??` that check if is `null` or `undefined`,

 if so then put `0` also that.

[image]

```js
this.x = _obj.x ?? ParentClass.previusX ?? 0;
this.y = _obj.y ?? ParentClass.previusY ?? 0;
this.z = _obj.z ?? ParentClass.previusZ ?? 0;
```

now instead of telling you `undefined` it will tell you `0`

[image]

```js
class ParentClass {
  constructor() {
    this.previusX = 0;
    this.previusY = 0;
    this.previusZ = 0;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(_obj) {
    super();
    this.x = _obj.x ?? ParentClass.previusX ?? 0;
    this.y = _obj.y ?? ParentClass.previusY ?? 0;
    this.z = _obj.z ?? ParentClass.previusZ ?? 0;

    this.result = "ERROR";
  }

  print() {
    this.result = `X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;
    this.setLastPosition();

    return this.result;
  }

  setLastPosition() {
    ParentClass.previusX = this.x;
    ParentClass.previusY = this.y;
    ParentClass.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

test();

function test() {
  // this is correct but in the next examples is not working because I wanted to that if _obj isn't defined it get the previus one.
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  }).print());

  // here since z is not defined
  // ❌ it need to be 3, but I don't know why is 0.
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 4,
    y: 5
  }).print());

  // ❌ this need to be "x: 4, y: 5, z: 3" by getting the previus values with "??"
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 3
  }).print());

  // ❌ this need to be "x:3, y:5, z:18"
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    z: 18
  }).print());

  // ✅ if there is all the values then is correct
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 8,
    y: 20,
    z: 30
  }).print());
}
```

now I think that the constructor that is inside `ParentClass()` isn't necessary anymore.

because also with that it will be always wrong (always `0`), but we can manually create it and access it by `parentClass.previusX`

> since `super();` is always necessary, but it takes a unnecessary variable that can maybe cause you some bugs.
> [image]

---

**so that it is,
here is the correct code:**

```js
class ParentClass {
  //not necessary for now.
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(_obj) {
    super();
    this.x = _obj.x ?? ParentClass.previusX ?? 0;
    this.y = _obj.y ?? ParentClass.previusY ?? 0;
    this.z = _obj.z ?? ParentClass.previusZ ?? 0;

    this.result = "ERROR";
  }

  print() {
    this.result = `X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;
    this.setLastPosition();

    return this.result;
  }

  setLastPosition() {
    ParentClass.previusX = this.x;
    ParentClass.previusY = this.y;
    ParentClass.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

test();

function test() {
  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  }).print());

  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 4,
    y: 5
  }).print());

  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 3
  }).print());

  console.log(new ChildClass({
    z: 18
  }).print());

  console.log(new ChildClass({
    x: 8,
    y: 20,
    z: 30
  }).print());
}
```